# TSQL - Parse XML metadata & values dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

**Background**
I have an XML column in my SQL table (using SQL Server). Each node has a different amount of metadata. For example, in the below example, Step Number 1 has the only "No" as metadata while, Step Number 2 additionally has RBuffer.

```
<Step No="1" >Step Number 1</Step>
<Step No="2" RBuffer="6000">Step Number 2</Step>
<Step No="3" Macro="5">Step Number 3</Step>
```

**Expected Output**

I'd like to extract this metadata dynamically while also grabbing the value. For the example above, this would look like the below table. Importantly, it shouldn't matter how many metadata tags there are, I want it to go through all of them. Some of my data has 10+ tags.

| Node | Step | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Step | 1 | Value | Step Number 1 |
| Step | 2 | RBuffer | 6000 |
| Step | 2 | Value | Step Number 2 |
| Step | 3 | Macro | 5 |
| Step | 3 | Value | Step Number 3 |

**Work so far**

So far, I've been able to extract the metadata in a static way:

```
SELECT o.value('@No', 'varchar(32)') [Step]
      ,o.value('@Macro', 'varchar(32)') [Macro]
      ,o.value('@RBuffer', 'varchar(32)') [RBuffer]
      ,o.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') [Action]
  FROM [dbo].[dw_mrd_vss_rundetail_stg] S
    CROSS APPLY S.[rundata_detail].nodes('Step') xmlData(o)
```

Which gives the following table:

| Step | Macro | RBuffer | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | Step Number 1 |
| 2 | NULL | 6000 | Step Number 2 |
| 3 | 5 | NULL | Step Number 3 |

But I have to explicitly call each value and creating columns in this way isn't scalable. Any help would be appreciated. I am relatively new to this kind of data munging in SQL, so explanations of code would be helpful.

Comment: @lptr,  looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic solution. If the "No" attribute is optional too and a node name is varying as well,

```
Declare @xml Xml = '<doc>
  <Step No="1" >Step Number 1</Step>
  <Step No="2" RBuffer="6000">Step Number 2</Step>
  <Step No="3" Macro="5">Step Number 3</Step>
  <Step Macro="7">Step Number 4</Step>
  <Node No="5">Step Number 5</Node>
</doc>';

select x.*
from @xml.nodes('/doc/*') d(dn)
cross apply (
  -- element data and "No" attr 
  select n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(32)') [node], 'Value' [Key], n.value('@No', 'varchar(32)') [Step], n.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') [Value]
  from d.dn.nodes('.') s(n)
  union all
  -- attributes data but "No"
  select n.value('local-name(../.)', 'varchar(32)') [node], n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(32)') [Key], n.value('../@No', 'varchar(32)') [Step], n.value ('data(.)', 'varchar(32)') [Value]
  from d.dn.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="No"]') a(n)
) x
```

Returns

```
node    Key Step    Value
Step    Value   1   Step Number 1
Step    Value   2   Step Number 2
Step    RBuffer 2   6000
Step    Value   3   Step Number 3
Step    Macro   3   5
Step    Value       Step Number 4
Step    Macro       7
Node    Value   5   Step Number 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `OUTER APPLY` a sequence containing the attributes and the inner text. Then for each of those, you can use `local-name(.)` to get the name of an attribute.

```sql
SELECT
  Node  = x1.step.value('local-name(.)','varchar(20)'),
  Step  = x1.step.value('@No','int'),
  [Key] = x2.vals.value('if (local-name(.) = "") then "Value" else local-name(.)','varchar(20)'),
  Value = x2.vals.value('.','nvarchar(100)')
FROM dw_mrd_vss_rundetail_stg s
CROSS APPLY s.rundata_detail.nodes('/Step') x1(step)
OUTER APPLY x1.step.nodes('(./@*[local-name(.) != "No"], ./text())') x2(vals);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cf28cbbd91c6033e32d52cbefff89d4)

If you want to include all nodes, even ones that are not `Step`, just change the first `.nodes` to `.nodes('/*')`

Comment: ..step elements without text (node) and no other attribute (but No) will not be included

Comment: @lptr You're right, needs to be `OUTER APPLY`